# Python Classes with methods

Tags: python, class

Write the definition of a class Counter containing:

- An instance variable  counter of type int , initialized to 0.
- A method called increment that adds one to the instance variable  counter . It does not accept parameters or return a value.
- A method called get_value that doesn't accept any parameters. It returns the value of the instance variable  counter .

This is what I have so far...

```
class Counter(object):
    def __init__(self, ct):
        self.counter = ct
    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
    def get_value(self):
        return self.counter
```

Comment: I don't see "instance variable counter of type int , initialized to 0"

Comment: My code lab says that I'm using an incorrect number some where in the solution. I'm not sure how to fix it....

Comment: @user3583742, what exactly are you trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: what is the purpose of `get_value`? You can access `counter` directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python class and methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552760/python-class-and-methods)

Answer (score 2):

Try to initialize instance variable counter to 0 in **init** method:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.counter = 0
```

Rest of the code is ok.

Comment: I have enter what you have typed under, def __init__(self, ct):
        self.counter = ct. But it gives me the same error.

Comment: replace your def __init__(self, ct)... code with above code

Comment: class Counter(object):
-----def __init__(self):
----------self.counter = 0
-----def increment(self):
----------self.counter += 1
-----def get_value(self):
----------return self.counter

Comment: That is what I have entered, still not taking it. I'm confused and not sure whats my mistake here.

Comment: Have you tried to create an instance of Counter class and use defined
methods on that instance?

Comment: @user3583742. If you have tried fixing your code and it does not work edit your question to show what you have tried,don't post code as a comment.

Comment: Sure. I will post it again with corrections..